# Acceleo Compiler (.mtl to .emtl) for version 3.7.x

Tags: acceleo

I'm trying to search for the alternative approach to compile Acceleo to generate .emtl from .mtl file using Acceleo Parser version 3.7.x outside eclipse but had not luck.
AcceleoCompiler(Helper) which we are currently using is already deprecated 
Please advise for other approach. 
Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Lea